# Pandas, dataframe and creating an error message in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pandas, csv

I have a function that searches a csv database file for a disease (for example melanoma). The function will then produce a list of gene symbols that match the disease name in the file. However I want to create an error message that will be produced if the disease is not found within the file (for example Epilepsy is not in the database). Below is the code I have (including an if statement that DOES NOT work). I'd really appreciate any help!

```
disease='melanoma'

input_file="curated_gene_disease_associations.tsv" 


def select_disease_df(input_file,disease):
    df=pd.read_csv(input_file, sep='\t')
    selection=df['diseaseName']==disease
        if disease not in df['diseaseName']:
            raise Exception("Disease not found in database")
    my_list=(df[selection]['geneSymbol']).tolist() 
return(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same code, I would just do something like:

```
def select_disease_df(input_file, disease):
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep='\t')
    selection = df['diseaseName'] == disease
    if sum(selection) == 0:
        print('Disease not found in the database')
        return []
    else:
        my_list = (df[selection]['geneSymbol']).tolist()
        return my_list
```

It's hard to see why your if statement doesn't work if you don't post some data.